# Flagged duplicate declined; closed anyway

Tags: discussion, flagging, duplicates

I'm new to photo.se, but have been around other SE sites for a while. I just wanted to check whether I'm actually doing the right thing and it was just a mis-click, or if there's a bit of a different protocol 'round these parts I haven't yet familiarized myself with

I flagged this post:

[How to recreate the perspective and field of view of an existing photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/51891/how-to-recreate-the-perspective-and-field-of-view-of-an-existing-photo)

As a duplicate of this:

[How to determine camera location from an existing photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50816/how-to-determine-camera-location-from-an-existing-photograph)

It is now closed as duplicate, but my flag was declined. If the decline was a simple mis-click of the button, I won't give it a second thought. But I wanted to double check: is it discouraged to flag duplicates of your own posts (I answered the one I linked to), as that might be seen as self-serving or something? Is there something else I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an initial reaction that changed, so a little too quick on the draw. :) There's no negative to you, flagging duplicates of your own is fine and fairly frequent around here.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarity.